# Binding commands to interactions such as MouseLeave?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

I have been trying to find the simplest method (in XAML) to bind a command to a control interaction, such as MouseLeave.

I have tried using EventTriggers but was unable to determine the correct structure for command binding, can anyone sugest something to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most kosher way of doing this is using attached properties. An excellent implementation of that can be found here:
http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/

Comment: Is there any non third party way?

Comment: The code is open source, so you can have a look at it. Basically he uses Attached Properties and Reflection to find the Event the command is talking about, and re-direct it to execute a command if fired. Its really quite elegant and does everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Interactions` & `Interactivity` ([Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801)) allow for this using triggers and the `InvokeCommandAction`. It also boils down to [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) and hinding all the imperative code in class-implementations.